# Using ActionListener within a Controller in a MVC setup

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm writing code for an assignment where I need to follow the Model-View-Controller design pattern to create a basic game. The game involves an 8x8 array of JButtons that need to be selected/deselected in a specific order to win.

From what I can tell, the loop that declares & instantiates each JButton and adds the actionListeners should be found inside the View class, while the ActionListeners that are attached to each JButton should actually trigger an EventHandler in either the Model class or the Controller class (because according to MVC I shouldn't write my EventHandler logic inside the View). This creates a problem because unless I attach my ActionListeners to each JButton from within my Model or Controller class, the EventHandler inside the Model or Controller class will not trigger.

What's the usual approach to fixing this issue? How should I arrange getters and setters to communicate ActionEvents between classes? Can I call my Controller or Model EventHandler from within the EventHandler of my View class? Finally, do EventHandlers belong inside the Model Class or the Controller Class?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the canonical solution since I'm not a professional nor an academician, but possible solutions:

- Create an ArrayList or other collection (a HashMap could work nicely here) of JButtons as well as a getter  method that uses either an int index (if an ArrayList) or a String (if a HashMap). This will allow the Control to access the buttons of the list and insert the Actions or ActionListeners.
- Use anonymous inner classes for your JButton Actions or ActionListeners, and have these listeners call methods of the Control that corresponds to the button's desired action.
- Have the control call a method on the view that both creates the button and adds the button's AbstractAction. I like the decoupling that this gives you.
- Use anonymous inner listener classes in the view, and all that they do is fire a SwingPropertyChangeListenerSupport (that all Swing components have innately) notifying any listeners (here the control object), that a state change (a button press) has occurred. Perhaps the button's ActionCommand could be the newValue parameter of your PropertyChangeEvent object. Of course the Control would have to add a PropertyChangeListener to the view and listen for these notifications of change.
- Decouple and and all of this via Juice or Spring.

---

So for instance if you go with the third recommendation above, your view could have something like:

```
// public method inside of View that Control calls
public void addActionToActionBar(Action action) {
  JButton button = new JButton(action);
  // actionBar would be a JPanel that holds a certain type of button
  actionBar.add(button);
}
```

Then the `for` loop to create your buttons could be all inside of the Control class.